# Which article do I use for a "concept" that introduces the actual thing

Tags: articles

Which article do I use for something that has't yet been made or introduced.

For example, consider a new website being built and the designer tells me, "We need to create an/the author's page for the new site."

Both the designer and I know about the author's page (we discussed it previously), but it only exists in idea and the final version may differ a lot from how we might have envisioned it.

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I'd certainly say 'We are working on the index of our book', but then everyone is familiar with that term and concept.

Answer (score 2):

You're choosing between:

> We need to create an author's page for the new site.

This sentence is valid if there is to be one or more author's pages on the new site.

> We need to create the author's page for the new site.

This sentence is *only* valid if there will only be one author's page.

The first sentence is fine for both contexts.

Comment: Please don't use `code` quoting in place of traditional formatting like block quotes and italics.

Comment: Better? Sorry about that, I found this site from stackoverflow.